# Refresh JTabbedPane component

Tags: java, swing, refresh, repaint, jtabbedpane

I am trying to implement JTabbedPane. In the following code I have presented a case very similar to what I want to implement. I have created a tab by adding a JPanel to the JTabbedPane. I have added a JButton and JScrollPane to the JPanel. On click of the JButton I want to add a new JPanel having some JRadioButtons to the JScrollPane. But these are not shown even after refreshing the JScrollPane or main JPanel. Please help. The code is given below.

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Test {

    static JFrame frame;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}

private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Create and set up the window.
    frame = new JFrame("DynamicTreeDemo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JTabbedPane tp = new JTabbedPane();
    final JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane();
    JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    JButton jb = new JButton("Refresh");
    jb.setActionCommand("Show");
    jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           if(e.getActionCommand().equalsIgnoreCase("Show")){
               JRadioButton jrb1 = new JRadioButton("First Option");
               JRadioButton jrb2 = new JRadioButton("Second Option");
               JRadioButton jrb3 = new JRadioButton("Third Option");
               ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
               bg.add(jrb1);    
               bg.add(jrb2);
               bg.add(jrb3);
               JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
               p.add(jrb1);
               p.add(jrb2);
               p.add(jrb3);

               jsp.add(p);
               jsp.revalidate();
               jsp.repaint();
           }    
        }
    });

    jp.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
    jp.add(jb);
    jp.add(jsp);
    tp.add("First Tab", jp);


    frame.getContentPane().add(tp);                

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To add something to `JScrollPane` use its `JViewport` rather than directly calling `add()`. In your example replace:

```
jsp.add(p);
```

with:

```
jsp.getViewport().add(p);
```

Alternatively, initialize `JScrollPane` with a `JPanel` that holds other components. Based on your example:

```
final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
final JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(panel);

panel.add(new JRadioButton("First Option"));
panel.add(new JRadioButton("Second Option"));
panel.add(new JRadioButton("Third Option"));
```

See [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

The components should be added to the `JPanel` called `jp` rather than directly to the scroll pane.

Answer (score 3):

JScrollPane only works with a single "View". You cannot add components to the scrollPane. If you want, you can change the "View" using `setViewPortView()`. To achieve the behaviour you are looking for, do the following:

```
JPanel centralView = new JPanel();
// possibly configure that central view with appropriate layout and other stuffs
JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(centralView);
```

...
   // Now you can add your components to centralView instead of your jsp.add(...) calls.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the `JPanel` to the `JScollPanes` *viewport* using `getViewport()`, then repack the `JFrame` to get the sizing issue sorted using `pack();`:

```
           jsp.getViewport().add(p);
           frame.pack();
```

instead of:

```
           jsp.add(p);
           jsp.revalidate();
           jsp.repaint();
```

Comment: I would not recommend to use pack() once a frame is visible because it can be very disturbing for the user to have a frame that resize itself. If you need to sort layout issues, usually calling revalidate() on the affected containers is enough.

Comment: aaacccch pack could be contraproductive, do you paleontolog ??? +1 for stonedges `getViewport().add()`, but basic stuff is setViewport() `Removes the old viewport (if there is one); forces the viewPosition of the new viewport to be in the +x,+y quadrant; syncs up the row and column headers (if there are any) with the new viewport; and finally syncs the scrollbars and headers with the new viewport.
Most applications will find it more convenient to use setViewportView to add a viewport and a view to the scrollpane.`